# Looping through sets of three columns & copy row (3 columns) then loop onto next set of 3 columns

Tags: excel, vba

*I am writing a macro that takes booked holiday one sheet & compiles it onto one column in another sheet.<
Each month has 3 columns (a,b,c). Then the next month is (d,e,f), moving across the sheet until column (AJ)
Column a *date
column b * hours taken
comn c *agreed/declined.
The next month would be
Column *  date<
column *  hours taken
comn *  agreed/declined.
It only copys the row if column (b)  if greater than 0.1 hours
Have written code to loop through first month, but how do i get it to then loop through next 11 months ( 11 sets of three columns) from left to right?*

```
Sub CopyACross()

Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, erow As Long,

lastrow = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow

Sheets("sheet1").Select


If cells(i, 2).Value > 0.1 Then

Range(cells(i, 1), cells(i, 3)).Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets("sheet4").Select

erow = ActiveSheet.cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.cells(erow, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End If
Next i



End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to embed your existing code in another loop that counts the columns. The code below isn't tested. Please alert me to any typos it might contain.

```
Sub CopyAcross()
    ' 015

    Dim WsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, R As Long, eRow As Long
    Dim C As Long

    Set WsTarget = Worksheets("Sheet4")
    With WsTarget
        ' count the rows in the same sheet where you set the range
        eRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    For C = 0 To 11
        With Worksheets("Sheet1")
            ' count the rows in the same sheet where you set the range
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, (C * 3 + 1)).End(xlUp).Row

            For R = 2 To lastRow
            '    Sheets("sheet1").Select        ' don't Select anything
                If .Cells(R, (C * 3 + 2)).Value > 0.1 Then
                    eRow = eRow + 1
                    .Range(.Cells(R, (C * 3 + 1)), .Cells(R, (C * 3 + 3))).Copy _
                            Destination:=WsTarget.Cells(eRow, 1)
                End If
            Next R
        End With
    Next C
End Sub
```

I have taken the liberty to remove all the selections your code makes. They aren't necessary and just blow up the volume of code while slowing its execution.

Comment: That is what i am wanting to acheive, but when i paste in your code it comes back with run time error '1004' "application-defined or object defined error" on the "erow=" line.

Comment: Yes, my bad. Sorry about that. Both for eRow and lastRow the code should be `.Cells(...` instead of `.Range(...`. I'm modifying my post to that effect.

Comment: Works perfectly now, Appreciate the help

Comment: Great! I'm glad I could help. As a guide to other readers - and to increase my fame - please select the answer.